# Подстроить текст под ширину блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть поп-ап  и у него прописана ширина.
Я добавляю два div

```
<div class="storeAddress_inner">
  <div class="storePhoneNumber" style="white-space: nowrap;">Phone Number: 02077 159241</div>
    <div class="storeRangeChillerFreezer" style="white-space: nowrap;display: inline-block;">
      <span class="range_information">
        <img src="">
        <span class="range_information_msg" style="display: inline-block;">
          We have a chiller
        </span>
        <br>
        <img src="">
      <span class="range_information_msg">
        We have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezerWe have a freezer
      </span>
    </span>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

и  когда в div`е storeRangeChillerFreezer в span добавляю много текста, появляется полоса прокрутки.

Как сделать так, чтобы прокрутка не появлялась, а текст автоматически переводился на новую строку?

Спасибо

Comment: Вопрос: У вас код целиком, или вы последний `div` при копировании потеряли?

Comment: Тогда оформите свой комментарий как ответ, пожалуйста, чтобы другие участники не отвлекались на более неактуальный вопрос.

Comment: Дело скорее не в том, чтобы другие не отвлекались — а в том, чтобы обозначить верное решение. Оно наверняка пригодится кому-нибудь ещё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправила это, когда убрала `white-space: nowrap`. Все заработало.